# (MRC) When my button addTarget, the Analyze memory warning disappear. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

When code haven't [btn release],Product > Analyze, I understand that I get memory warning. Potential leak of an object stored into 'btn'.

but when my button addTarget, warning disappear! Why?

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

- (void)btn_click:(UIButton *)btn
{
    NSLog(@"123");
}
```

Comment: just out of interest, why are you using MRC?

Comment: because I take over my friend's project